# How to center and fix a position?

Tags: css, button, center

I'm trying to fix a button to page. I'm not pro but here it is;

```
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#181516;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}

.bg {    
    background:url(../images/entrance.jpg) no-repeat center center ; 
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And the butttons;

```
.door {
    display:inline-block;
    width:170px;
    margin-top:22%;
}
```

But on the smaller or much bigger screens button goes wherever it wants :D

It has to be fixed into a square. Back picture is a little door. And the button must be inside of that door... MArgin or padding px or % always the same. Can you help me?

Comment: Can your put your code into jsfiddle?  I would say that you need to position your door centrally in a div, then position the button absolutely inside that div.  But a fiddle will help to demonstrate.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/brbap/1/ its like that. if you want i can upload the web site so you see the images too. I used center tags but i prefer css codes. But  i couldnt center it with css. I tried to fix a button right bottom corner i couldnt manage that either :D If you help me i will be sooo glad. I'm about the get mad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly i.e. that you want to have a div that always stays in the center of the screen.

Basically the way I do this is by positioning it absolute and 50% from the top side and the left side of the screen. Then the top-left point of the div is in the center, to fix that I use half of the div's size as negative margin to position move it back up to the center.

So basically the following:

> .door{
>       position: absolute;
>       top:50%;
>       left:50%;
>       width:170px;
>       height:200px;
>       margin-left:-85px;
>       margin-top:-100px;
>       background-color:#fff;
>       }